# implementing a factory that registers non-static member functions to it in C++

Tags: c++, function, factory, member

I have a C++ singleton factory-like class called MemMgr which is in charge of managing heap memory for objects in a library:

```
#include <vector>
class MemMgr
{
    public:

        // Callback interface of functions to register with MemMgr
        typedef size_t (*MemSizeFunc)(void);

        void Register(MemSizeFunc memSizeFunc);

        static MemMgr & GetInst(void);

        // more public functionality related to managing memory

    private:

        // a vector (not a map) of functions pointers to keep track of
        std::vector<MemSizeFunc> m_memSizeFuncs;

        MemMgr(void);
        MemMgr(MemMgr const &);
        MemMgr & operator= (MemMgr const &);

        // more private functionality related to managing memory
};
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to have objects of any classes that would like to utilize managed memory be able to register themselves with MemMgr via a (**non-static**) member function which will calculate and return the amount of managed memory that that particular object needs.  Something like the following:

```
class MemMgrUser
{
    public:

        MemMgrUser(void)
        {
            MemMgr::GetInst().Register(GetManagedMemSize);
        }

    private:

        size_t GetManagedMemSize(void)
        {
            // calculations involving member variables
        }
};
```

(Then, prior to MemMgr actually allocating any memory, it would query the size-related functions registered to it in order to find out the amount of memory to allocate.)

However, the compiler yells at me when I try the above approach b/c I am trying to register member function pointers, not plain-vanilla function pointers.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could implement such functionality?  I am having problems seeing how a template implementation (or polymorphic one) would be implemented.

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: Use `std::function<size_t()>` (or `boost::function`, if you do not have access to C++11 libraries).

Comment: If I understand, you try to get the size of an object by using one of its member function, but before the creation of the object itself ? That doesn't sound possibl (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Mankarse, thank you!  That did, indeed, work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even try to register a member function pointer. That would have to be specified as `&MemMgrUser::GetManagedMemSize`. You can't use the plain name of a member function, except in an expression that calls it.

But even if you had a member function pointer, it cannot be used in the same way as a plain function pointer of the same apparent signature. Calling a member function always requires an object to call it on. The `this` pointer available in the function is an additional, hidden parameter.

If you can use features of the C++11 standard library, you could `typedef std::function<size_t (void)> MemSizeFunc;` instead of the current typedef. That allows you to store various kinds of functions and function objects that are callable with that signature as a `MemSizeFunc`. In particular you could register your `GetManagedMemSize` member function bound to a suitable `MemMgrUser` object, for example as:

```
MemMgrUser()
{
   MemMgr::GetInst().Register(std::bind(&MemMgrUser::GetManagedMemSize, *this));
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm!  Thank you!